# Id field showing null while saving data in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-rest-framework

Whenever I try to add new record to the database using django rest api, it is showing 'null' in the `id` field.

I have attached my serializers code and views code.

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createcustomer(request):
    serializer = Customerdetailsserializer(data=request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # some_dict = {'id': serializer.data['id']}
        serializer.save()
    else:
        pass
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class Customerdetailsserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customerdetails
        fields = '__all__'
```

Help me to fix This

[OUTPUT image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X662j.jpg)

Comment: As long as the data is not saved (`serializer.save()`), it is not stored in the database, hence it has no primary key.

Comment: Could you please post your models.py as well? It would help us troubleshoot.